# Efficient method for determining directional change in landcover polygons between two time points?

Tags: arcmap, land-cover

I have polygons of landcover classes in ArcMap (dense forest, sparse forest, wetland, water, rock) for a landscape from two different time points. I want to determine the % or total area that changes from one landcover class to the others between the two time periods. I know that I can likely do this all feature-by-feature using the "Intersect" tool, but is there a tool or extension that would streamline this process?

Comment: Add field short in both, populate it by, 1,2,4,8, 16 for dense, sparse, etc. Do similar for second using 32, 64, 128... Total of 2 fields in intersection layer is your answer. E.g. 65 = from dense to sparce.

Comment: @FelixIP very clever!  I like that.